# Delete record showing error Use of undefined constant classid - asumed 'classid'

Tags: php, mysql

Getting error on delete record "undefined constant classid - asumed 'classid'"

here is the query code

```
         <?php

                $query = "SELECT `add_class`.`class_id` AS classid,`add_class`.`class` AS class_title, COUNT(*) AS 'total' FROM `add_class`  INNER JOIN `add_sec_class` ON (`add_class`.class_id = `add_sec_class`.class) GROUP BY `class_title` HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1";

                include("include/my_pagina_class.php");
                $test = new MyPagina;
                $test->sql = $query; // the (basic) sql statement (use the SQL whatever you like)
                $test->rows_on_page = 50;
                $result = $test->get_page_result(); // result set
                $num_rows = $test->get_page_num_rows(); // number of records in result set
                $nav_links = $test->navigation(" | ", "currentStyle"); // the navigation links (define a CSS class selector for the current link)
                $nav_info = $test->page_info("to"); // information about the number of records on page ("to" is the text between the number)
                $simple_nav_links = $test->back_forward_link(); // the navigation with only the back and forward links
                $total_recs = $test->get_total_rows(); // the total number of records
                //echo $errNo;
                $rowCount = 1;
                $listRows = $total_recs;
                $counter = 1;
                while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
                {
                      $counter++;

              ?>
                <tr>
                  <td height="22" align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="CheckBoxChild" id="CheckBoxChild" value="<?=$row[classid]?>" onclick="SelectChildCheckBox(this.form,'CheckBoxParent','CheckBoxChild');" /></td>

                  <td><?=$row['class_title']?></td>
                  <td><?=$row['total'] ?></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td></td>
                  <td><a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>?id=<?=$row[classid].''.rebuild_qstring("id")?>">Edit</a></td>
                </tr>
              <?php }?>
```

and these are my tables

table1 name "add_sec_class" 
columns are: d_id, class, division, ddate, username, acadmic_year, status

table2 name "add_class"
columns are: class_id, class, acadmic_year, status, display _order, fee

Now what should i write instead of $row[classid], I am not sure what kind of change is required in query.

Thanks in advance for your precious time

Comment: $row[classid] should be $row['classid']

Comment: i tried this too but it is giving same error

Comment: In your query: classid should be `´classid´` and class_title should be `´class_title´`

Comment: Every field in your query must have this symbol `´`

Comment: Great! it is working Fine now. Thank you So Much :)